# How to write database undependent test plan?

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I define test cases when I make assertions that are database dependent.

```
Eg: Expect user with username:testusr password:pws123456 to be able to authenticate
```

When databases changes test execution report change.

**What are the best practices to have database undependent test plan ?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what this question is about?

Comment: the problem I want to solve is that my test cases use assemptions that the existing database contains some predefined initial data. I want to make them more undependent. example of initiale data: user table containes user with testusr username and pws123456 password. if the database doesn't contain this test execution report will get failure even if code is doing what is expected